# How do set a declared parameter through multiple select queries

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I need to set a parameter so the person who executes the query only has to modify the parameter in one place versus having to set it in every Where clause for the multiple queries.

I keep getting an error "Must declare the scalar variable "@REGION", and I am at a loss for how to solve this with what I have researched. Additionally, my assumption is that the code could be more optimized however that is beyond my technical ability, and would also be beyond the person who executes this codes ability.

```
USE ADMIN;
DECLARE @REGION NVARCHAR(255)
SET @REGION = 'Region 20 - Midwest';

SELECT [Account Code Description]
    ,[Level 3 Organization Name]
    ,COUNT([Code - Fix Comp]) AS WO_VOL_52
    ,CAST((CAST(SUM([Code - Fix Comp]) AS FLOAT)/CAST(COUNT([Code - Fix Comp]) AS FLOAT))  AS DECIMAL(18,3)) AS OTC_52
    ,CAST((CAST(SUM([Code - Manager Comp]) AS FLOAT)/CAST(COUNT([Code - Manager Comp]) AS FLOAT))  AS DECIMAL(18,3)) AS MR_52
    ,CAST((CAST(SUM([Code - Disagree Comp]) AS FLOAT)/CAST(COUNT([Code - Disagree Comp]) AS FLOAT))  AS DECIMAL(18,3)) AS SAT_52
    ,CAST((CAST(SUM([Code - Recall]) AS FLOAT)/CAST(COUNT([Code - Recall]) AS FLOAT))  AS DECIMAL(18,3)) AS RECALL_52

FROM [dbo].[Manager Review Data]

WHERE [52WK] LIKE 'YES'
    AND [Account Code Description] NOT IN ('Insurance','RECURRING SERVICES')
    AND [Level 3 Organization Name] = @REGION

GROUP BY [Account Code Description],[Level 3 Organization Name]
```

I expect that when the parameter is set, that using the @Region will call that parameter in all queries for which the variable is used.

Comment: I would suggested using a user-defined table function that takes the parameter as an argument.  You still have to provide the argument to all the `select`s, but it seems easier to pass it as an argument.

Comment: Gordon - thank you for the response, do you have any sample code on how I could try your suggestion, or a link to a page that would outline on how I could try that?

Answer (score 0):

Typically I use a metadata table for this type of functionality. The sample code below gives you a prototype for a metadata table. The user would execute the [utility].[set__metadata] procedure to set the value, then you would have all your scripts call the inline function to get the value. Alternately, you could "set" a lot of metadata values and simply have a single variable to set at the top of each script for the user to type in what is being searched for.

Let me know if you have questions. You'll find it to be a very useful construct both to keep from hard coding constants in your code (which require the code to be rebuilt/redeployed), to easily change values wherever they occur in your code, and to give simple, easy to remember names to those values. I typically use "category.class.type". You should probably use some standardized naming convention. I avoid upper case because of the potential for casing errors (.NET components are selectively case sensitive). But use a naming convention that makes sense for you.

You might also decide to add a "list" view or function so that you or another use can easily see all the available metadata values.

```
use [test];

go

if schema_id(N'utility') is null
  execute (N'create schema utility');

go

if object_id(N'[utility].[metadata]', N'U') is not null
  drop table [utility].[metadata];

go

create table [utility].[metadata]
  (
     [key]     [nvarchar](256)
     , [value] [nvarchar](256)
  );

go

if object_id(N'[utility].[set__metadata]', N'P') is not null
  drop procedure [utility].[set__metadata];

go

create procedure [utility].[set__metadata] @key     [nvarchar](256)
                                           , @value [nvarchar](256)
as
  begin
      merge into [utility].[metadata] as [target]
      using (values(@key
            , @value)) as [source] ([key], [value])
      on [source].[key] = [target].[key]
      when not matched then
        insert ([key]
                , [value])
        values ([key]
                , [value])
      when matched then
        update set [target].[key] = [source].[key];
  end;

go

if object_id(N'[utility].[get__metadata]', N'FN') is not null
  drop function [utility].[get__metadata];

go

create function [utility].[get__metadata] (@key [nvarchar](450))
returns [nvarchar](256)
as
  begin
      declare @value [nvarchar](max)

      select @value = [value]
      from   [utility].[metadata]
      where  [key] = @key;

      return @value;
  end;

GO

execute [utility].[set__metadata]
  @key = N'region.southwest.texas'
  , @value=N'hot and humid';

go

execute [utility].[set__metadata]
  @key = N'region.pacific_northwest.seattle'
  , @value=N'cold and rainy';

go

select [utility].[get__metadata](N'region.southwest.texas');

go 

select [utility].[get__metadata](N'region.pacific_northwest.seattle');

go
```

Comment: Great thank you very much, I will give this option a try.